# Collectionview - GridItemsLayout, possible to vary span according to row?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a vertical list and GridRowSpan set to 2

However, I would like to have one single large 'header' item for the top

Using alternate layouts doesn't seem appropriate given GridRowSpan is set at the outset

The ability to specify alternate layout template based on some criteria only comes after this point, so it's not going to have any effect on the above, correct?

Can anyone advise an easy way therefore to have effectively an alternate layout from a dynamic list of content, so only the first item spans two columns and everything else is laid out in rows of 2?

Comment: No ,it's impossible , grid row span apply on every items , i think maybe you need  [header view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#display-a-templated-header-and-footer) .

Comment: I took a look at headerview thanks, it seems very confusing to use. I think I shall just abandon both and attempt to implement myself the long winded way

Comment: Feel free to share your answer here if problem gets resolved .